# Visibility change on div with time (Contact Form 7)

Tags: forms, wordpress, contacts

I am using WordPress. My contact form plugin is "contact form 7". If your email fails or succeeds, it says sucessfull or not sucessful. I want to attach javascript to it and locate it in middle of my contact so if it fails box opens up says it failed and it disappears, samething for success. I also would like page to change to homepage if mail sent successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this only for the normal use of the form, and not for some fancy special feature - Contact form 7 already have this function .

The default message is (red box ) "Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method."

you can change this message in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

seems like this could be done pretty easily with jQuery, no?  just look for the submit button to be clicked, validate, and then run your actions.
you could either use an alert, or have a hidden div on the page that you change to display:block, throw a timer on that to hide it (or a close button), and just set the html text to 'success' or 'fail' respectively.  then when the div is set to close, and was successful, throw a url redirect.
i know that is pretty vague, but not sure of your level of expertise.

Comment: I am not good with Javascript and jQuery. This is wordpress plugin so I am not sure how can I add submit event.